# armv7 not being added while creating static library

Tags: ios, objective-c, arm64

I'm creating a static library in iOS. When I check for architecture of library using the command

> lipo -info {LibraryName}.a

I'm getting only `arm64` as the architecture for library. I also need `armv7` to be included for this library so that I can integrate it with another app and archive it.

In the Architectures I've selected Standard architectures

> (armv7, arm64) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)

And for Valid architectures I've arm64 armv7 armv7s

please help me.

Comment: Surely you mean for valid architectures you have arm64,armv7,armv7s? Not in a single word? (Edit: I checked and Xcode displays them with a space separator, and when you click Xcode shows each on a single line)

Comment: @Clafou They are added separately, I'm just trying to show the visual aspect of my Xcode because currently I'm not allowed to post a picture

Comment: OK -- just looks odd, as Xcode shows them space-separated

Comment: @Clafou Yes, they are space separated. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Clafou I'm using XCode 7.1 to create libraries

Comment: Could it possibly have anything to do with the "build active architecture only" setting? Or with different configurations for Debug and Release?

Comment: Found the answer ?

Answer (score 2):

Also check your iOS deployment target. If it's 12.1 for example it won't include armv7.

Comment: Thanks, I had exact this problem in the new static library!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that **Build Active Architecture Only** is set to **No**.  (This is under *Build Settings* in the *Architectures* group).

I had a similar problem and this seems to fix it.

*(Now I just need to understand why `armv7s` is no longer included and if it matters...)*

Answer (score 0):

In addition to making sure **Build Active Architectures Only** is set to **No**, check the format of **Valid Architectures**. I have accidentally typed `armv7, arm64` – notice the comma – on multiple occasions now, and it does not give you an error or warning. It simply builds arm64 by default. Correct it by removing the comma, like this: `armv7 arm64`.